# Triangle inequality question on norm space

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

I'm trying to decide if $||v||=x^2+y^2$ 
defines a norm on $\Re^2$. It's been a long time since I prove normed spaces so please excuse me by being a rookie.

1) I'm having trouble specifically trying to prove the triangle inequality. I'm not sure if I'm correct but here's what I got:

Let $v,w \in \Re^2, then $ $||v+w||=||(x_1^2+x_2^2) +(y_1^2+y_2^2)||\le (x_1^2+y_1^2) +(x_2^2+y_2^2)=||v||+||w||$

2) As for the rest of the properties, here's what I have (if I'm missing something I'd appreciate any corrections):

N1) $||(x,y)|| \ge 0$ is evident since $x^2$ and $y^2$ are both positive.

N2) $||(x,y)||=0 \implies x=0=y$ so then $v=(0,0)$

N3) $||\alpha (x,y)||=||\alpha (x^2+y^2)||=|\alpha| ||x^2+y^2||=|\alpha | ||v||$

As always, I'm very grateful for your help. Thank you.

Comment: You might want to double check N3)

Comment: Am I missing a step?

Comment: What do you mean by a norm of a scalar?

Comment: It's incorrect - the first step should be computed as $\parallel \alpha v \parallel = (\alpha x)^2 + (\alpha y)^2.$

Comment: I think you're looking for $\mathbb R$ instead of $\Re$ which is `\mathbb{R}` instead of `\Re`

Comment: @Kaster yes I see what I did wrong. So is my triangle inequality applied correctly?

Comment: @User69127 I wonder, did you mean to write $||v||^2=x^2+y^2$ where $||v||=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ ? Of course, what has been discussed shows why the posted formula fails.

Comment: @JamesS.Cook No I didn't mean to write that. Thanks for checking though. The norm you stated actually works for scalability

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\|u\| = x^2+y^2$, then
$$
\|u\| = x^2+y^2 \ge 0
$$
and obviously $\|u\| = 0$ iff $u = \mathbf 0 = (0,0)$.

As for the absolute scalability, 
$$
\left \| \alpha u\right \| = \left (\alpha x \right )^2 + \left ( \alpha y\right )^2 = \alpha^2 \left ( x^2+y^2\right ) = \alpha^2 \| u\|\ne \left |\alpha \right | \|u\|
$$
so, no, $d^2(\mathbf u) = x^2+y^2$ is not a norm.

Now, even though we concluded that $d^2$ is not a norm, we can check if triangle inequality holds for that function.
\begin{align}
\|u+v \| &= \left ( x_1+x_2\right )^2 + \left (y_1+y_2 \right )^2 = x_1^2+2x_1x_2 +x_2^2 + y_1^2+2y_1y_2+y_2^2 = \\
&= \left ( x_1^2+y_1^2\right )+\left ( x_2^2+y_2^2\right ) + 2x_1x_2+2y_1y_2 = \\
&= \| u \| + \| v \| + 2x_1x_2 + 2y_1y_2
\end{align}
so, you can see now, that depending on $u$ and $v$, $\| u + v \|$ might be greater than $\| u\| + \|v\|$, less or equal to it.

Comment: Thank you, Kaster. But what about my triangle inequality? Was it applied correctly?

Comment: @User69127 no, it wasn't applied correctly. I'll expand my answer in a bit.

Comment: I definitely did it wrong. I see my mistake. I'm good to do other examples now thanks to your help. Very much appreciated.